# Woocommerce: Display "From" price range that ignores "Price on request"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi, I hope I can explain what I'm looking for...
I have a shop with variable products that sometimes have regular prices, but sometimes a product may consist of variation 1 ($ 5), variation 2 ($ 10) and variation 3 ("Price on request").

If the product only consists of "real" prices, the shop overview correctly displays the price as "From $5". But if there's written text in there, it doesn't display any price at all. The thing is, I want the system to treat "Price on request" as if it was basically $ 99,999 or something like that, so it still displays the product as "From $ 5".

What's the best way to achieve this? My knowledge of PHP is very limited, so I don't even know where to begin and what's the correct syntax...

The code that is currently creating the "From" prices looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {

  // Main Price
  $prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
  $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( ' FROM &nbsp; %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

  // Sale Price
  $prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ));
  sort( $prices );
  $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( ' ab &nbsp; %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
  if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
    $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
  }

  return $price;
}
/* End */
```

The products that are listed as "Price on request" are internally set as "not in stock" with a price of $ 0.0. Here's the code that transforms "not in stock" to "Price on request":

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability_text', function($text, $product) {
    if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
        $text = 'Price on request';
    }

    return $text;
}, 10, 2);
```

Can I somehow hook an additional piece of code in there that does something like

```
if (one or more of the variants == out of stock) {
from-price-function checks for the lowest available price !==0 of the other variants;
}
```

?

Comment: Actually, what if I tried this:
1. Set every "price on request" product to $ 9999.
2. Tell the "price on request" function not to look for "out of stock", but to look for "price == 9999".
Wouldn't that fix the "From $ XX" problem because $ 9999 is always gonna be the highest number and it shouldn't ever appear as the from-price?

The only problem is I have no clue as to how to code the part with `if (price == 9999) {display "price on request"};`

_edit: Holy cow, comment formatting is a nightmare here. Just let me do line breaks..._

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and it was surprisingly simple... 
All I had to do was to leave the "price on request" function alone and instead change another function that I hadn't mentioned here:
A function that says "If price != 0, display price, else nothing". I simply changed it to "If price <9999, display price, else nothing":

```
//Hide Price when Price is Zero
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html','maybe_hide_price',10,2);
function maybe_hide_price($price_html, $product){
     if($product->get_price()<9999){
        return $price_html;
     }
     return '';
 }
```

Now it hides the internal "Price on request" price of $ 9999 and the "From: " function can keep working the way it did before. Only gotta change every former 0-variant to 9999 now and it's all good.